# What happens to String[] from and int [] to when I override newView/bindView in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

Before I was extending SimpleCursorAdapter and overriding newView/getView I would specify which TextView's to populate with the to and from parameters in the constructor.

Now when I did override, the to/from parameters seem to be useless. If I don't pass a column name to "from" I can still access the column and at the same time I can't construct the adapter by passing null to both to/from (so I just pass one column not to get NullPointerException).

**Should I be using to and from somehow in bindView? If so, how?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now when I did override, the to/from parameters seem to be useless.

A `SimpleCursorAdapter` is designed(as its name suggest) as a simple adapter to bind a limited range of views to a `Cursor`'s data, mapping made through the two arrays(the columns names to views with the specified ids). If you override the `SimpleCursorAdapter` (especially the `newView()` and `bindView()` methods that do the binding)then those columns aren't really necessary because you'll take matters into your own hands.

> If I don't pass a column name to "from" I can still access the column and at the same time I can't construct the adapter by passing
>   null to both to/from (so I just pass one column not to get
>   NullPointerException).

Although you'll probably do the mapping yourself(I don't know what methods you override and how) those columns are used in other part of the adapter's code so passing `null` for either one of those arrays should be avoided. Anyway the real problem is that the `SimpleCursorAdapter` is a simple class design for basic scenarios. If you find the need to override it then you better extend its super class `CursorAdapter`(which comes without those arrays) and do whatever you want.

> Should I be using to and from somehow in bindView? If so, how?

As those arrays represent the columns from the `Cursor` and the ids of the views to which to bind the data then it would make sense to use them.

Answer (score 0):

these can be empty for `customAdapter` because you can control TextView's etc from `getView()`

so you can either have control from `to/from parameters`

or from `getView()`